# Create a table from CSV columns in SQL Server without using a cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

Given a table:

```
|Name    | Hobbies                |
-----------------------------------
|Joe     | Eating,Running,Golf    |
|Dafydd  | Swimming,Coding,Gaming |
```

I would like to split these rows out to get:

```
|Name    | Hobby     |
----------------------
|Joe     | Eating    |
|Joe     | Running   |
|Joe     | Golf      |
|Dafydd  | Swimming  |
|Dafydd  | Coding    |
|Dafydd  | Gaming    |
```

I have completed this below (example is ready to run in SSMS), buy my solution uses a cursor which I think is ugly. Is there a better way of doing this? I am on SQL Server 2008 R2 if there is anything new which will help me.

Thanks

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Split]') and xtype in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')) drop function [dbo].Split
go
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )


go

declare @inputtable table (
    name varchar(200) not null,
    hobbies varchar(200) not null
)

declare @outputtable table (
    name varchar(200) not null,
    hobby varchar(200) not null
)

insert into @inputtable values('Joe', 'Eating,Running,Golf')
insert into @inputtable values('Dafydd', 'Swimming,Coding,Gaming')

select * from @inputtable

declare inputcursor cursor for
select name, hobbies
from @inputtable

open inputcursor

declare @name varchar(255), @hobbiescsv varchar(255)
fetch next from inputcursor into @name, @hobbiescsv
while(@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) begin

    insert into @outputtable
    select @name, splithobbies.s
    from dbo.split(',', @hobbiescsv) splithobbies

    fetch next from inputcursor into @name, @hobbiescsv 
end
close inputcursor
deallocate inputcursor

select * from @outputtable
```

Comment: Even though in your example each person has exactly three hobbies, I assume that each person can actually have 1 or more hobbies?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables yes, I should have mentioned the hobbies list can be of arbitrary length

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a string parsing function like the one found [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1665). The key is to use [CROSS APPLY](http://thesqlagentman.com/2010/01/cross-apply/) to execute the function for each row in your base table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnParseStringTSQL] (@string NVARCHAR(MAX),@separator NCHAR(1))
RETURNS @parsedString TABLE (string NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @position int
   SET @position = 1
   SET @string = @string + @separator
   WHILE charindex(@separator,@string,@position) <> 0
      BEGIN
         INSERT into @parsedString
         SELECT substring(@string, @position, charindex(@separator,@string,@position) - @position)
         SET @position = charindex(@separator,@string,@position) + 1
      END
     RETURN
END
go

declare @MyTable table (
    Name char(10),
    Hobbies varchar(100)
)

insert into @MyTable
    (Name, Hobbies)
    select 'Joe', 'Eating,Running,Golf'
    union all
    select 'Dafydd', 'Swimming,Coding,Gaming'

select t.Name, p.String
    from @mytable t
        cross apply dbo.fnParseStringTSQL(t.Hobbies, ',') p

DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fnParseStringTSQL]
```

Answer (score 4):

Create this function in your DB:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@origString varchar(max), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(max))     
as     
begin     
    declare @idx int     
    declare @split varchar(max)     

    select @idx = 1     
        if len(@origString )<1 or @origString is null  return     

    while @idx!= 0     
    begin     
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@origString)     
        if @idx!=0     
            set @split= left(@origString,@idx - 1)     
        else     
            set @split= @origString

        if(len(@split)>0)
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@split)     

        set @origString= right(@origString,len(@origString) - @idx)     
        if len(@origString) = 0 break     
    end 
return     
end
```

and then simply call it in your Select statement and use cross apply to join to the function

```
Select t.Name, 
       s.items as 'Hobby'
from dbo.MyTable as t
Cross Apply dbo.Split(t.Hobbies,',') as s
```

Comment: Nopers. You have to either cross apply or outer apply a TVF.

Comment: @Denis - thanks Denis.  forgot I was dealing with Table Function there.  Updated my answer now.

Comment: Thanks, `cross apply` is what I was after! WIll do some more reading on that now

Answer (score 4):

Just do the following:

```
select *
from @inputtable
outer apply dbo.split(',', hobbies) splithobbies
```

Comment: There is no native "split" function in SQL Server (which sucks).

Comment: @Philip The answer is given in the context of the question. Did you see that there's already a splitting function implemented at the very beginning of the question? So, it's alright.

Comment: is correct, the outer apply is the part I needed to know so this answer is perfectly valid

Comment: Fair enough. I just read the intro implying it was a typical cursor-based looping solution, saw everyone else's posted splitting functions, and assumed this was like all the other string-parsing questions posted on SO. Alas, votes (down or otherwise) cannot be reversed unless the original reply is modified; if you (add a space, change some punctuation), I'll reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer to use `XML` to split CSV list to table valued format. You can check this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

and the following [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for more techniques showing how to do this. Then, you just need to use `CROSS APPLY` clause to apply the function.