# Condition on the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

My script has a variable that does not always contain a value. If there is a value, I need an extra `WHERE` clause.

```
DECLARE @identityUserIds NVARCHAR;
SELECT @identityUserIds = (SELECT TOP (1) [userIdsCsv] FROM [identityUsers])

SELECT *
FROM [Users]
-- IF (!ISNULL(@identityUserIds) OR @identityUserIds != '')
WHERE [ID] in (@identityUserIds)
-- ELSE (no extra condition)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I suspect your `in` condition won't work how you want it to, because the `userIdsCsv` value is just a string with commas in it, not a set of numbers. You will need to split it up first, e.g. as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735152/most-succinct-way-to-transform-a-csv-string-to-an-table-in-tsql)

Comment: That is correct, but here is just a pseudo code to illustrate the actual problem. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this is:

```
 ... where @identityUserIds is null or ID in (@identityUserIds)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't that `@identityUserIds != ''` part important?

Comment: @RenéVogt Might be, depending on whether `userIdsCsv` allows and/or can contan empty strings

Comment: I assumed that it does because it was part of OP's query.

Comment: `ID in (@identityUserIds)` will still be evaluated and will fail if `@identityUserIds = ''`

Answer (score 0):

I think this can simply be done with an `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Users]
WHERE Len(ISNULL(@identityUserIds,''))=0
    OR [ID] IN (@identityUserIds)
```

But note that @Rhumborl's comment is correct, the `IN` statement will not work with a string. Unfortunatly I have no immediate solution for *that* problem.

Answer (score 0):

...where ID in (ISNULL(@identityUserIds,ID))